Video Not Displaying on Vercel Deployment in Django Project (Works Locally)
I'm working on a Django project where I'm displaying a video using the  tag. The video works perfectly on my local development server, but once I deploy the project to Vercel, the video does not load.
Here’s the HTML code I’m using to display the video: 


I tried using both {{ video_url }} and the {% static %} tag to load the video file from the static/videos directory. I also ensured the video file was collected using collectstatic and updated the vercel.json file to serve static files correctly.
I expected the video to load and play as it does on the local development server. However, after deploying to Vercel, the video doesn’t show up at all. No error messages are shown in the browser console.
